# How to access fontforge from a Python script

Tags: python, fontforge

I need to use 'fontforge' extension for Python on Ubuntu.

I've tried to install 'fontforge' Ubuntu package using the following commands:

```
> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fontforge/fontforge
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install fontforge
```

But it didn't help because when I try to import and use 'fontforge' in Python interpreter, I get errors.

For exampple,

```
>>> import fontforge
>>> font = fontforge.open('filename')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'fontforge' has no attribute 'open'
```

What additional steps should I do to make it work?

Comment: Show the output of `pip3 show fontforge`

Comment: It's strange but after I tried removing/reinstallating of 'fontforge' Ubuntu package I'm not able even to import it in Python interprpeter. 'import fontforge' now returns: ImportError: No module named 'fontforge' Not sure why import was possible at the beginning.

Comment: Can i expect a straight answer to a straight question ?

Comment: The issue was solved by building fontforge from the source code. Thanks for the assistance.